# Can't Understand IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

I don't know if this is a simple problem or not, but I just can't see what the problem is. I've gotten three reports now from my app in Google Play of an IndexOutOfBoundsException at `points.get(++i)`.

```
public GameThread(SurfaceHolder sHolder, Context context, Handler handler)
{
    points = new ArrayList<Float>();
    running = true;
    mSurfaceHolder = sHolder;
}
protected void doDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    p.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
    {
        float x = points.get(i);
        float y = points.get(++i);

        canvas.drawPoint(x, y, p);
    }
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{   
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    points.add(x);
    points.add(y);

    return true;
}
```

The index it fails at is trying to access the location equal to its size (Actually one error says 
`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2205, size is 2206` which makes NO sense at all to me), and its size varies.

The only way I can see this happening is if for some reason only one object is added to points, and I don't know why that would happen. `onTouchEvent` isn't running in its own thread, is it?

Comment: Where is points defined? Is this a multi-threaded program/app?

Comment: Isn't a point itself an object with a x,y pair?

Comment: Something funny here, should you be incrementing your for loop by i+=2?  What is point?  A Point object?

Comment: points is just an array of ints. What's a Point object? It sounds like that might be a better choice.

Comment: I can only see the error message you're getting showing up if threads are involved (ie something is manipulating the collection size while the message itself is printing) Are you creating any threads yourself in the app?

Comment: Change it to `for (i = 0; i < points.size(); )` and later `x = points.get(i++);`, same for y.

Comment: Where is "points" cleared out? I assume it's not growing forever...? If that's in a separate thread, that may be your problem.

Comment: Actually it is growing forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is at this line:

```
float y = points.get(++i);
```

When `i = points.size()-1`, you preincrement, and then you invoke `points.get(++i);`. At this point, `i = points.size()` => Out of bounds. Just remove the `++` to fix it.

**EDIT**
Alternatively, you can try this approach:

```
List<Point> points = ...

protected void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   Paint p = new Paint();
   p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
   p.setColor(Color.WHITE);

   for (Point p : points) {
      canvas.drawPoint(p.x, p.y, p);
   }
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {   
   float x = event.getX();
   float y = event.getY();

   points.add(new Point(x, y));

   return true;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough. Yes, that's why it's crashing, but why isn't there another item in there? The size of the array should always be an even number.

Comment: Yes the size should be even, except if the `doDraw()` method is invoked by another thread just between `points.add(x);` and `points.add(y);`. It could happen ...

Comment: Is that possible? Can doDraw() be invoked again before it even finishes?

Answer (score 1):

I would make the for-loop safe from problems like this by letting the for loop construct handle all of the `i` variable logic, don't try to do it yourself.

```
for (int i = 0; i+1 < points.size(); i+=2){
    float x = points.get(i);
    float y = points.get(i+1);

    canvas.drawPoint(x, y, p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your for-loop.  While the first access would work, the second access is not guaranteed to be correct.  If you only have one object, then the loop can't work because you are trying to access the next element in the array, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

suppose your array length is **10**

```
 float y = points.get(++i);
```

you can replace this statement by
                          ^^^

```
float y = points.get(i+1);
```

You are increasing value of Y here as well as here

```
for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
                                   ^^^
```

In for loop it checks `i<points.size()` means it **9** or less than **9**

when you reach to **9**
and in for loop you are accessing `points.get(++i);` 
it will access `points.get(10)` <-------- here you gets exception

and your arry is **0-9** then is no element at **10**

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 for (int i = 0; i < points.size()-1; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your Point object correctly, like:

```
Point point = new Point();

point.x = value;
point.y = value;
```

to print, or use.. its just point.x and point.y still. (in case of `android.graphics.Point;`)

If you want to store several points, you can use for example ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Point> pointArray = new ArrayList<Point>();
pointArray.add(new Point(event.getX(), event.getY()));
```

To loop it throught:

```
    for(Point p : pointArray){
        // do something with p.x and p.y
    }
```